# AJAX at regular interval

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm calling ajax at regular interval (10 sec) from javascript to load data from the db. The response is listed in a small div. But once every 10 sec, I face the problem of interface not responding to user actions like mouse click, key press etc. Any help on this topic would be appreciated.

Code

```
var onlineLeads = function () {
var reqst ="";
var size="";
var url ="<s:property value="str_applicationPath"/>/Marketing/Online_showNewRequest";   
xmlHttp.open("POST", url, false);                                           
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {

//Code for display

}
}
xmlHttp.send(); 
setTimeout(onlineLeads, 15000);
};
setTimeout(onlineLeads, 1000);
```

Comment: please provide code or jsfiddle or demo, we are not psychics

Comment: Is it synchronous? Just post your code.

Comment: @Blender Sorry for missing the code. Please see my edits.

Comment: @Dogoku Sorry for missing the code. Please see my edits

Comment: @Barmar Sorry for missing the code. Please see my edits

Comment: @user2151071: Yep, it's synchronous.

Comment: I was close, it's on line 5.

Comment: @Blender will try by making is asynchronous. Thank You for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't performing Ajax:

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", url, false); 
//                        ^^^^^ 
//        Puts the request into synchronous mode
```

In synchronous mode, the call blocks until the response comes back. This ties up the JS event loop.

Change `false` to `true`.

Comment: Thank You all for the fast reply. Let me try it.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the issue. But I got a doubt. If more than one ajax calls is present, will it create any problem if i use this request in Synchronous Mode

Comment: If you are in synchronous mode then you can't have more than one request at a time, it locks up the JS thread entirely — that's the problem you are having.

Comment: Actually I'm using this ajax response in a small div at the right portion of the interface. It is calling at regular interval . Ajax is also used in the main interface section. So will it be a problem if both ajax requests occurs at the same?

Comment: There is no intrinsic problem with having multiple Ajax requests going at the same time. On a slow connection, with frequent updates, the build up and overlap, which is usually undesirable (for the waste of resources if nothing else). Avoid that by firing requests only when the previous response has come back.

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try it that way.